# Not able to give connection from files to UIText field in interface builder

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface

I have three views in view based application. In  third view i have this code in .h file

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


    @interface ViewThreeController : UIViewController {

        IBOutlet UITextField *Firstname;
    }

    @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *Firstname;

    @end
```

and in .m file i have this line

```
#import "ViewThreeController.h"


@implementation ViewThreeController

@synthesize Firstname;

@end
```

in interface builder for files owner i given ViewthreeController.I was dropped round rect button in view. Now i want to connect from files owner to Firstname text field.But i am not able to connect from files owner to text field.
      Can any one help me regarding this...

Comment: ViewthreeController is not real name: it is ViewThreeController

Comment: sorry for mistake me also given the same ViewThreeController

Comment: are you trying to connect a UIButton with a UITextField ?

Comment: I am trying to connect from  inspector Firstname to UIButton

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect a UIButton in nib file to UITextField declared in file owner. If you really need a UITextField, then remove that button and add a UITextField control to the nib file.